# Pyinstaller: Linux executable giving syntax error: unexpected "("?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, pyinstaller, embedded-linux

I have used pyinstaller to build a script on Linux version 2.6.30 and the executable works fine on my system. It also ran fine on another system running Linux 2.6.35. However, I need the executable to run on an embedded system which runs a stripped down version of Linux 2.6.30. When trying to execute the Linux app on the system I get the following error:

`./app: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("`

I am not sure what files/libraries have been removed from the embedded system. Are there any particular Linux dependencies that PyInstaller has? I have tried googling the exact Linux dependencies but I was not able to find anything.

Here is the complete list of libraries present on the system:

[image: List of Libraries]

Not sure if it is of use but this is the spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['app.py'],
             pathex=['/Server Code'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('app_data/*', 'app_data'), ('static/css/*', 'static/css'), ('static/js/*', 'static/js'), ('templates/*', 'templates'), ('flask_config.py', 'flask_config.py')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='app',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Comment: Something is telling me that there is no Python available at all. Usually embedded systems are fighting for each extra kilobyte of memory.

Comment: I do not have Python installed on the embedded system, but I thought the whole point of PyInstaller was that it bundles everything into a standalone executable? Because the application ran fine on a fresh install of Linux 2.6.30 which had only Python 3.4 installed where as the application was built using Python3.6.

Comment: The error message looks like it is trying to run `app` as a shell script.

Comment: I see. Kernel does not understand binary format of the given file. It may be because of several reasons: libraries incompatibility, architecture incompatibility, kernel doesn't support other binary formats than compiled-in, ...

Comment: Is there any way to drill down on the root cause of the problem or identify why it is interpreting it as a shell script and not as an executable?